# "CMD + tab" makes me lose album view when switching back to iTunes

Tags: itunes, keyboard, shortcut

This behaviour is hard to reproduce and doesn't happen everytime.
But I have been able to catch it happening with a screengrab.

I am playing an album in iTunes and have iTunes set to album view, then switch from iTunes to Safari (or another app, but Safari is used in this example) using `cmd` then `Tab`:

[image]

Then I want to switch back from Safari (or another app) to iTunes, and sometimes, when I press `cmd` + `Tab`, the album view suddenly collapses and I get this:

[image]

It's very annoying because I have to press `CMD`+ `L` to get back to the song currently playing.

I am not sure why it does that - it's not everytime. It's not the behaviour I get when I only press `Tab` or `cmd` while in iTunes...

**Mac**: iMac with Yosemite.

**iTunes**: 12.3.2.35

**Keyboard**: French Apple extended keyboard.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it and since you said it's hard to reproduce as it doesn't happen every time I suggest you edit your question and add what version of OS X and iTunes you're running and if there is anything else you can think of that's common when it does reproduce.

Comment: Thanks, I will. I will also try and grab a screen capture at some point to share it in the question if I can.

Comment: @user3439894 I just updated the question with GIF screen grabs